# How to create new handshake method and crl

Tags: openssl

I'm try to develop OpenSSL to support a new handshake method that is not SSL and TLS or any other default handshake method. I developed an engine that support new algorithm on digest, cipher and pkey and now want implement in in OpenSSL using a new handshake method and crl.

1. can embed handshake method and crl generator in engine?
2. what is best solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: [Directly Read/Write Handshake data with Memory BIO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22753221) and [Use OpenSSL with a custom channel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14685539)

Comment: thank you,but i want completely change the handshake on openssl,because i want this change be apply on openssh an other application that use openssl. develop an engine for openssl is a good solution for this job but in engine we can add new handshake method or not ?
on libssl any version of ssl use SSL_METHOD but in this structure there is not handshake steps and sequence of data that send and received

Comment: the right way for edit handshake in connect method for any version of ssl.in this function sequence and data that transmit during handshaking detect by enumeration and value in ssl object.